# Mounting with bindfs without nautilus noticing

Tags: linux, mount, fuse

I want to user-mount a directory to some other directory without the need for superuser rights. I found the fuse tool bindfs does exactly that BUT nautilus will show every mount in its sidebar. The tool I'm writing will mount a lot of different directories dynamically so it would be a bit annoying to see all those mounts in the file manager changing all the time.

Is there something I can do about that? Or is there a better tool than bindfs?

Thank you.

Comment: Try mounting under `/mnt`: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7828748/fuse-filesystem-hide-from-nautilus

Answer (score 0):

This is a small workaround..

You could press the small triangle next to the "Devices" button in the side bar..This collapses the Devices tree.