# FUSE filesystem hide from nautilus

Tags: c, linux, fuse, nautilus

I have written a FUSE driver for linux, and when I mount it I get an entry in the nautilus sidebar. I do not want this - the unmount button doesnt even work. I would like to hide this entry in the nautilus sidebar for my mounted fuse filesystem. I dont want to add it to the fstab because running it as root opens security holes. Is there anything I can add to the options line or the code itself to prevent it from showing in nautilus?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe Nautilus will only show those sidebar entries if your mount point is under `/media` (the designated path for "removable media" under the [FHS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filesystem_Hierarchy_Standard)).

Using a mount point under `/mnt` should make Nautilus ignore the filesystem.

Comment: Actually, it was mounted under /home/(username)/ but thanks it seems to work. I'll set up some links to the /mnt folder now.